# Importing data from a webpage written in script (seajs) to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I would like to ask about how can we get the data from an HTML which is using JavaScript to show data in a table.

http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/

I need to extract various kinds of currency exchange rates from the site - from USD to other currency and vice versa. I tried to use the <kbd>Get External Data</kbd> > <kbd>From Web</kbd> function in Excel, but the website may protect these kind of queries, so I cannot get the table I want (error message saying the currency ex rate I'm looking for does not exist). Because I need to input the original currency and target currency in the website, I cannot get the table without inputting the org and target currency. This is the only recognize site the company uses, so I have to stick with this site.

Everyday I need to convert up to 2k times, is there any VBA for me to use so that I could run the code to auto extracting the exchange rates?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh because i'm very new to coding, i tried with the solution given by SO and edit a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the last 60 days and output to a csv file on your desktop. You can change the "USD" part of the URL as required.

```
Sub GetRates()

    Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object

    myURL = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download?quote_currency=USD&end_date=" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-m-d") & "&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=d60&price=bid&view=graph&base_currency_0=CAD&download=csv"
    sFilename = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rates.csv"


    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2
       oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works smoothly.  may i know if you can also extract the data for this site as well?
http://shippingma.alibaba.com/solution/shipping_lcl_list.htm?dep=CNSHA&des=DEHAM&weight=1000&volume=1

Comment: At first glance, it looks like that data only comes in the format of a HTML table - so you would need to scrape that data, it won't parse to csv format.

Comment: S O, i checked the sources code of the html structure.  it is using JSON.parse to load a file in their server i guess... scrape the data meaning?

Comment: It's off-topic to this question though - please post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much @S O!  because i'm new to code, i made some adjustment to your code to get various type of currency pair exchange rate.

i saved org currency list in col A and target currency list in col B.

below is the code i use:

```
Sub GetRates()

Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

With ActiveSheet
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow

myURL = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download?quote_currency=" & Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value & "&end_date=" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-m-d") & "&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=d60&price=bid&view=graph&base_currency_0=" & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & "&download=csv"
sFilename = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & ".csv"

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2
   oStream.Close
End If

Next i
End With
```

End Sub